# Windows 10: Start menu slow to respond to keyboard

Tags: windows-10

Just upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10.

The start menu is responsive to pop up and search/navigate.

The Start menu pops up and, with a mouse click, the application launches quickly.

However, if I use the keyboard, there is a profound (3+ second) delay from the time I hit [enter] to when the app starts. E.g.

1. <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>
2. notepad   // this is typed
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. // delay
5. Notepad launches

How do I chase this down?

My new laptop does not have this problem. But my recently upgraded desktop is a dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of trial and error, discovered the cause was an older version (3-4 years) of UltraMon was the cause.

Uninstalled UltraMon (which I don't need on Windows 10 anyway) and all is solved.