# One application (Steam) lagging when hitting “Enter” after searching on Windows Start menu

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-search, steam

My question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1082576/windows-10-start-menu-slow-to-respond-to-keyboard/1825714).

I've noticed that my problem only happens with Steam (so far), there is a delay between me hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Steam actually starting. The delay is not due to Steam loading anything, I can see clearly that nothing is happening and then after some seconds the Windows Search menu finally closes and Steam starts to load, this happens even when Steam is already running on the background and I just want to bring it up.

In comparison with Notepad or my browser, whenever I hit enter Windows Search menu closes instantly and I can see that the applications are loading or they just open right away.

In the linked post, the author mentioned that he managed to debug and find that this issues was cause by an app called UltraMon, and I don't see this app installed in my PC so I guess the root cause for my problem is different.